# Search filter based on rating

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I'm try to build a little filter based on the ranking ( numeric value stored in a string ) , but I'm stuck with a part of the code.

***Expected behaviour***

When a User click on the `select` option the elements that doesn't match the value selected have to hide(not remove).

```js
$(".notSearched").hide();

$("select").on("click", function() {
  let selectedValue = this.value;
  $('.card-wrap').each(function(selectedValue) {
    console.log("sei qua");

    if (selectedValue === "0") {
      return
    }
    let rate = $(".restoName").find(".ratePlace").text();
    let numRate = parseInt(rate);
    if (rate !== selectedValue || rate !== (selectedValue + 0.5)) {
      $(this).addClass("notSearched");
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="columnsContainer">
  <div class="leftColumn">
    <div class="filterResearch">
      <select name="filter" id="searchFilter">
        <option value="all">Apply a filter</option>
        <option value="1">1 Star</option>
        <option value="2">2 Stars</option>
        <option value="3">3 Stars</option>
        <option value="4">4 Stars</option>
        <option value="5">5 Stars</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <div class="rightColumn" style="margin-top:50px;">

      //Cards down below
      <div class="card-grid">
        <div class="card-wrap" id="">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/k4SSPK/Spinaci_Green_Dark_Blue.jpg " class="photo">
          <div class="restoName">
            <h3>Restaurant Name Here</h3>
            <p class="restoAddress">In questo posto ci andrà l'indirizzo del ristorante in questione, sarà una stringa lunga</p>
            <p class="ratePlace">Rating: 4,5</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-wrap" id=""><img src=" https://image.ibb.co/k4SSPK/Spinaci_Green_Dark_Blue.jpg" class="photo">
          <div class="restoName">
            <h3>Restaurant Name Here2</h3>
            <p class="restoAddress">In questo posto ci andrà l'indirizzo del ristorante in questione, sarà una stringa lunga222</p>
            <p class="ratePlace">Rating: 4,52</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-wrap" id=""><img src=" https://image.ibb.co/k4SSPK/Spinaci_Green_Dark_Blue.jpg" class="photo">
          <div class="restoName">
            <h3>Restaurant Name Here3</h3>
            <p class="restoAddress">In questo posto ci andrà l'indirizzo del ristorante in questione, sarà una stringa lunga333</p>
            <p class="ratePlace">Rating: 4,53</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have no errore in the console. Before the downvotes, I searched all the evening how to do, I will link here some links about it.

1. https://codepen.io/jsartisan/pen/wKORYL
2. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp
3. https://codepen.io/samyerkes/pen/Inaht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several issues here:

- Use the `change` event on `select` elements, not `click`
- The outer instance of `selectedValue` is not available within the `each()` as you've used it in the argument list of the handler function, so it becomes the index of the current element instead. This breaks the logic.
- The `text()` of `.ratePlace` is not an integer which can be parsed as it is prefixed with the text `Rating:`. Hence the output of `parseInt` is always `NaN`. To fix this you could put the rating value in its own `data` attribute to stop the confusion and need to parse the value
- You can put the check of `selectedValue` in the event handler, not the `each`, that way you can avoid the loop entirely if it's not needed

You can also use the `notSelected` class in CSS to hide the content, and then use `toggleClass()` in jQuery to hide/show the elements as needed. With all that said, try this:

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  let selectedValue = parseInt(this.value, 10) || 0;
  if (selectedValue === 0)
    return;

  $('.card-wrap').each(function() {
    let $cardWrap = $(this);
    let rate = $cardWrap.find(".ratePlace").data('rating');
    $cardWrap.toggleClass('notSearched', rate < selectedValue);
  })
});
```

```css
.notSearched {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="columnsContainer">
  <div class="leftColumn">
    <div class="filterResearch">
      <select name="filter" id="searchFilter">
        <option value="all">Apply a filter</option>
        <option value="1">1 Star</option>
        <option value="2">2 Stars</option>
        <option value="3">3 Stars</option>
        <option value="4">4 Stars</option>
        <option value="5">5 Stars</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div class="rightColumn" style="margin-top:50px;">
      <div class="card-grid">
        <div class="card-wrap">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/k4SSPK/Spinaci_Green_Dark_Blue.jpg " class="photo">
          <div class="restoName">
            <h3>Restaurant Name Here</h3>
            <p class="restoAddress">In questo posto ci andrà l'indirizzo del ristorante in questione, sarà una stringa lunga</p>
            <p class="ratePlace" data-rating="1.5">Rating: 1,5</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-wrap">
          <img src=" https://image.ibb.co/k4SSPK/Spinaci_Green_Dark_Blue.jpg" class="photo">
          <div class="restoName">
            <h3>Restaurant Name Here2</h3>
            <p class="restoAddress">In questo posto ci andrà l'indirizzo del ristorante in questione, sarà una stringa lunga222</p>
            <p class="ratePlace" data-rating="3.52">Rating: 3,52</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-wrap">
          <img src=" https://image.ibb.co/k4SSPK/Spinaci_Green_Dark_Blue.jpg" class="photo">
          <div class="restoName">
            <h3>Restaurant Name Here3</h3>
            <p class="restoAddress">In questo posto ci andrà l'indirizzo del ristorante in questione, sarà una stringa lunga333</p>
            <p class="ratePlace" data-rating="4.53">Rating: 4,53</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I changed some of the ratings to make the effect of changing the dropdown more obvious.

Comment: I choose your answer because your code is shorter and, for me, easier to understand. Thanks for the lesson i really appreciate everything ( how i wrong to set the body of the html ) and the way you clearly explained all of my error. Thank you. You made my day.

Comment: Just a little question, probably it's just a little bit off-this-topic, but this code has a strange behaviour if the cards are generated dynamically. If i set your last line `$cardWrap.toggleClass('notSearched', rate < selectedValue)` in this way  `rate < selectedValue` the cards go away, but if i left the code in his original form it doesn't work. It's a problem due to  [Event binding on dynamically created elements?
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: The elements are selected when the `change` event fires on the select, so the fact they are dynamically created shouldn't make a difference. I'd suggest starting a new question with a clear example.

Answer (score 1):

First of all , the each function will return a callback function with two parameter first fr index and seconde the current looping element , so no need to pass the selected value in param , so it'll be overided by index ;

You can apply regular expression to cut off the real number then use the [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Math/round) , in order to extract the real number , then replace the comma (,) by dot (.) (js recognize real by dot not comma)

and then make comparison to show , or hide you elemet by adding a `notSearched` class 
dont forget to add in css the

```
.notSearched {
  display:none;
}
```

Below a working snippet : that show only by number of start you can edit the condition (> , < , <= etc ...)

```js
$("select").on("click", function() {
  let selectedValue = this.value;
  if (selectedValue == "all") return;
  $('.card-wrap').each(function(index, element) {
    var text = $(element).find(".ratePlace").text();
    let number = text.match(/[0-9]*\,?[0-9]+/g);
    number = number[0].replace(",", ".");
    number = (Math.round(number));
    console.log(number, selectedValue ,   number >= selectedValue )
    number == selectedValue ? $(element).removeClass("notSearched") : $(element).addClass("notSearched");
  })
});
```

```css
.notSearched {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="columnsContainer">
  <div class="leftColumn">
    <div class="filterResearch">
      <select name="filter" id="searchFilter">
        <option value="all">Apply a filter</option>
        <option value="1">1 Star</option>
        <option value="2">2 Stars</option>
        <option value="3">3 Stars</option>
        <option value="4">4 Stars</option>
        <option value="5">5 Stars</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <div class="rightColumn" style="margin-top:50px;">

      //Cards down below
      <div class="card-grid">
        <div class="card-wrap" id="">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/k4SSPK/Spinaci_Green_Dark_Blue.jpg " class="photo">
          <div class="restoName">
            <h3>Restaurant Name Here</h3>
            <p class="restoAddress">In questo posto ci andrà l'indirizzo del ristorante in questione, sarà una stringa lunga</p>
            <p class="ratePlace">Rating: 4,5</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-wrap" id=""><img src=" https://image.ibb.co/k4SSPK/Spinaci_Green_Dark_Blue.jpg" class="photo">
          <div class="restoName">
            <h3>Restaurant Name Here2</h3>
            <p class="restoAddress">In questo posto ci andrà l'indirizzo del ristorante in questione, sarà una stringa lunga222</p>
            <p class="ratePlace">Rating: 2,2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-wrap" id=""><img src=" https://image.ibb.co/k4SSPK/Spinaci_Green_Dark_Blue.jpg" class="photo">
          <div class="restoName">
            <h3>Restaurant Name Here2</h3>
            <p class="restoAddress">In questo posto ci andrà l'indirizzo del ristorante in questione, sarà una stringa lunga222</p>
            <p class="ratePlace">Rating: 4,42</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-wrap" id=""><img src=" https://image.ibb.co/k4SSPK/Spinaci_Green_Dark_Blue.jpg" class="photo">
          <div class="restoName">
            <h3>Restaurant Name Here2</h3>
            <p class="restoAddress">In questo posto ci andrà l'indirizzo del ristorante in questione, sarà una stringa lunga222</p>
            <p class="ratePlace">Rating: 2,1</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-wrap" id=""><img src=" https://image.ibb.co/k4SSPK/Spinaci_Green_Dark_Blue.jpg" class="photo">
          <div class="restoName">
            <h3>Restaurant Name Here3</h3>
            <p class="restoAddress">In questo posto ci andrà l'indirizzo del ristorante in questione, sarà una stringa lunga333</p>
            <p class="ratePlace">Rating: 4,53</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```